# How do i write this to follow the instruction

Tags: java, for-loop

Write code that will print the following:

`0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9(x10)`

This is what i currently have:

```
for (int m=0;m<10;m++){
    for (int j=1;j<=10;j++){
        System.out.print(j);
    }
}
```

Comment: You've categorised this under javascript which it is not!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add carriage return

```
for (int m=0;m<10;m++)
       for (int j=1;j<=10;j++)
          System.out.print(j + " ");
System.out.println();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Antonie.(Works)

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a space.

```
System.out.print(j+" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can do as "one liner" by misusing the Java 8 streams API.

- closed range of integers, join using space
- pass into a stream generator, limit to 10 repeats, join with new line
- output

Code

```
System.out.println(Stream.generate(() -> IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 10)
                   .mapToObj(Integer::toString).limit(10)
                   .collect(Collectors.joining(" ")))
                   .limit(10).collect(Collectors.joining("\n")));
```

Output

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```